# Grails fields plugin - custom collection display members as links

Tags: grails, field

Scenario: an order show view with a transitive field, total cost. The transitive field is not rendered by the default fields generated view, so I had to manually specify the fields I want to see.  The below works fine:

`<f:with bean="customerOrder">
    <f:display property='token' wrapper="displayText"/>
    <f:display property='lineItems' wrapper="displayCollection"/>
    <f:display property='total' wrapper="displayMoney"/>
    <f:display property='dateCreated' wrapper="displayDate"/>
    <f:display property='customer' wrapper="displayLink"/>
</f:with>`

The displayCollection part is handled by a _displayWrapper.gsp file inside views/_fields/displayCollection/  It looks like this:

`<li class="fieldcontain" style="list-style-type: none;">
    <span class="property-label">${label}</span>
    <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="${property}-label">
        <ul>
            <g:each in="${value}" var="item">
                <li>${item?.toString()}</li>
            </g:each>
        </ul>
    </span>
</li>`

This is a generic collection display field.  It will work for articles in a cart, posts by a user, etc.  The only thing is, the collection member is displayed as only text, not a link.

If the ${value} is a single class member and not a collection, the _displayWrapper.gsp below works fine.

`<li class="fieldcontain" style="list-style-type: none;">
    <span class="property-label">${label}</span>
    <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="${property}-label">
        <g:link action="show" controller="${property}" id="${value?.id}">${value?.toString()}</g:link>
    </span>
</li>`

The question is, how can I derive the controller name from a member of a collection, the collection being obtained by ${value}?

I have installed the view templates, no luck there.  Similarly, I looked at the fields plugin code, no luck there either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

10 minutes later and I've done it.  The essence of the solution lies in the fact that the Grails controller name can be derived from the corresponding Grails domain class.  Here's what the relevant _displayWrapper should look like:

`<li class="fieldcontain" style="list-style-type: none;">
    <span class="property-label">${label}</span>
    <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="${property}-label">
        <ul>
            <g:each in="${value}" var="item">
                <li>
                    <g:link controller="${item.class.getSimpleName()[0].toLowerCase() + item.class.getSimpleName().substring(1)}" action="show" id="${item.id}">
                        ${item?.toString()}
                    </g:link>
                </li>
            </g:each>
        </ul>
    </span>
</li>`

One can also write a custom tag to do this.